# ReferenceError: navigation is not defined

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

i am newbie to react native, When i add a button for navigation, it show that **navigation is not defined**. I need some help.

````
import { Image,  Button,StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, ImageBackground, } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer, NavigationHelpersContext, StackNavigator, useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import HelloWorldApp from "./scholarship.js"

const HomeScreen = () => 
{
   <Button title="sample" onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('Scholarship')}></Button>
}
const Scheme = createStackNavigator();

function myScheme({navigation})
{
    <Scheme.Navigator>
        <Scheme.Screen name="Scholarship" component={HelloWorldApp}/>
    </Scheme.Navigator>
}

export default HomeScreen;```
````

Answer (score 1):

Use your Home component Like:-

```
const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  ........................
  .........
  }
```

this sholud solve your problem. the navigation lies in the props of the component
so to use is like navigation.navigate('') you have to destructure it from props.
like i did above .

Answer (score 0):

According to [React Navigation documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) you should use `useNavigation` hook:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const HomeScreen = () => 
{
   const navigation = useNavigation();
   return (
      <Button title="sample" onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('Scholarship')}></Button>
   );
}
```